# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show by using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit that

$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}
$$
Where $c\in(0,\infty)$ which is in the domain of $f$.

This is what I did: Fix $\epsilon>0$. I need to find $\delta>0$ such that

$$
0<|x-c|<\delta\Longrightarrow |\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}|<\epsilon
$$

I started with

$$
|\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}|=\frac{|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}|}{\sqrt{cx}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{|x-c|}
{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c})}
$$
but then I am not sure how to proceed. I am aware that I need to make

$$
\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c})>\text{something}
$$
but I am not sure how. I tried taking $|x-c|<\frac{1}{2}c$, this would give me $\frac{1}{2}c<x<\frac{3}{2}c$. However, if $0<x<1$, then $\sqrt{x}>x$ and if $x\geq1$, then $x\geq \sqrt{x}$ and this confuses me as what I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $x>(1/2)c$ implies that $\sqrt{x}>\sqrt{(1/2)c}$ and hence $1/\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c})<1/(\sqrt{(1/2)c}(\sqrt{(1/2)c}+\sqrt{c}))$ and this is just a constant, you are done.

Comment: I see. I actually have solved it but confused myself. Thanks